# How to get pedometer(stepcountvalue) data on Autoupdate basis from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, auto-update

I want to retrieve StepCountValue from firestore and display it to my app on realtimeAutoupdate basis. RealtimeAutoupdate basis means i want a realtime/without refreshing method.So, if a user cover some distance then he/she gets his/her total walking steps in app.

How to retrieve data from database and throw it in a container(page.dart)

How to get pedometer(stepcountvalue)  automatic changing data on Autoupdate and retrieve
With firestore

How to update this data to firestore automatically
[image]

This is my main.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/models/brew.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/screens/Pages/page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/services/database.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/pedometer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(new NewApp());

class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  String muestrePasos = "";
  String _km = "Unknown";
  String _calories = "Unknown";
  String stepCountValue = 'Unknown';
  String _showcoin = '0';

  StreamSubscription<int> _subscription;

  double _numerox; //numero pasos
  double _convert;
  double _kmx;
  double burnedx;
  double _coin;
  double _porciento;
  // double percent=0.1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //initPlatformState();
    setUpPedometer();
  }

  //inicia codigo pedometer
  void setUpPedometer() {
    Pedometer pedometer = new Pedometer();
    _subscription = pedometer.stepCountStream.listen(_onData,
        onError: _onError, onDone: _onDone, cancelOnError: true);
  }

  void _onData(int stepCountValue1) async {
    // print(stepCountValue); //impresion numero pasos por consola
    setState(() {
      stepCountValue = "$stepCountValue1";
      // print(stepCountValue);
    });

    var dist = stepCountValue1; //pasamos el entero a una variable llamada dist
    double y = (dist + .0); //lo convertimos a double una forma de varias

    setState(() {
      _numerox = y; //lo pasamos a un estado para ser capturado ya convertido a double
    });

    var long3 = (_numerox);
    long3 = num.parse(y.toStringAsFixed(2));
    var long4 = (long3 / 10000);

    int decimals = 1;
    int fac = pow(10, decimals);
    double d = long4;
    d = (d * fac).round() / fac;
    print("d: $d");

    getDistanceRun(_numerox);

    setState(() {
      _convert = d;
      print(_convert);
    });
  }

  void reset() {
    setState(() {
      int stepCountValue1 = 0;
      stepCountValue1 = 0;
      stepCountValue = "$stepCountValue1";
    });
  }

  void _onDone() {}

  void _onError(error) {
    print("Flutter Pedometer Error: $error");
  }

  //function to determine the distance run in kilometers using number of steps
  void getDistanceRun(double _numerox) {
    var distance = ((_numerox * 76) / 100000);
    distance = num.parse(distance.toStringAsFixed(2)); //dos decimales
    var distancekmx = distance * 34;
    distancekmx = num.parse(distancekmx.toStringAsFixed(2));
    //print(distance.runtimeType);
    var coiny = ((_numerox * 125) / 100000);
    coiny = num.parse(coiny.toStringAsFixed(2));

    setState(() {
      _km = "$distance";
      //print(_km);
    });
    setState(() {
      _kmx = num.parse(distancekmx.toStringAsFixed(2));
    });

    setState(() {
      _coin = num.parse(coiny.toStringAsFixed(2));
      //print(_coiny);
    });
  }

  //function to determine the calories burned in kilometers using number of steps
  void getBurnedRun() {
    setState(() {
      var calories = _kmx; //dos decimales
      _calories = "$calories";
      //print(_calories);
    });
  }

  void coins() {
    setState(() {
      var showcoin = _coin;
      _showcoin = "$showcoin";
    });
  }

  //fin codigo pedometer

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print(_stepCountValue);
    getBurnedRun();
    coins();
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().step,
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: const Text('Step Counter'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('logout'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _auth.signOut();
                    }
                ),
          FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            label: Text('New Page'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pages()));
            }
          ),
          ],
          ),

            body: new ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  width: 250,
                  //ancho
                  height: 250,
                  //largo tambien por numero height: 300
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment
                            .bottomCenter, //cambia la iluminacion del degradado
                        end: Alignment.topCenter,
                        colors: [Color(0xFFA9F5F2), Color(0xFF01DFD7)],
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
                      )),
                  child: new CircularPercentIndicator(
                    radius: 200.0,
                    lineWidth: 13.0,
                    animation: true,
                    center: Container(
                      child: new Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.walking,
                              size: 30.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            //color: Colors.orange,
                            child: Text(
                              '$stepCountValue',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.purpleAccent),
                            ),
                            // height: 50.0,
                            // width: 50.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    percent: 0.217,
                    //percent: _convert,
                    footer: new Text(
                      "Steps:  $stepCountValue",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          color: Colors.purple),
                    ),
                    circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                    progressColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 100,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 80.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/distance.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "$_km Km",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white54,
                        ),
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(
                        width: 20.0,
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 80.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/burned.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(
                        width: 20.0,
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 80.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/images/step.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                  width: 150,
                  //ancho
                  height: 30,
                  //largo tambien por numero height: 300
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "$_km Km",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(
                        width: 20.0,
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "$_calories kCal",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(
                        width: 5.0,
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              "$_showcoin Coins",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my wrapper.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_testing/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/screens/authenticate/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null){
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return MyApp();
    }

  }
}
```

this is page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/main.dart';

class pages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _pagesState createState() => _pagesState();
}

class _pagesState extends State<pages> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              label: Text('back'), onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp())
                );
            }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is database.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_testing/models/brew.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference brewCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('step');
  Future<void> updateUserData(int stepCountValue, int _calories, int _km , int _showcoin) async {
    return await brewCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'stepCountValue': stepCountValue,
      '_calories': _calories,
      '_km': _km,
      '_showcoin': _showcoin,
    });

      // get brews stream
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get step {
    return brewCollection.snapshots();
  }


}
```

this is brew.dart

```
class Brew {

  final int stepCountValue;

  Brew({ this.stepCountValue });

}
```

I hope this is enough to solve my problem. I'm very new to Flutter and I dont know much about firebase and firestore, so it would be nice, if you can say where EXACTLY I have to change WHAT or add WHAT. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  There's a lot of code here, and you should narrow the problem down to the lines that are problematic.

Comment: can you help me now

Comment: have you made this app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query in the _onData() function of your main.dart file this will update the data automatically whenever there will be any change in your steps. And you can retrieve data in real time using streamBuilder easily.

for example:

```
void _onData(int stepCountValue1) async {
// print(stepCountValue); //impresion numero pasos por consola
setState(() {
  stepCountValue = "$stepCountValue1";
});
final CollectionReference brewCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('step');
await brewCollection.document(uid).setData({
  'stepCountValue': stepCountValue,
});
}
```